# Elasticsearch: count returning wrong value

Tags: elasticsearch

ES 1.7.3

We have around 20M documents. Each document has a unique ID. When we do a count-request (/index/type/_count) we get around 30K less documents than we indexed.

I checked the existence of each document by making requests on the ID field. Result: there is none missing.

Is there any reasons why `_count` returns not the exact count?

PS: I read about estimates when doing aggregations. Is this perhaps related?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Coutn API` may result in inaccurate  results. You can use `search_type=count` instead. It works in the same way as `searching` works but returns only `count`.

Use it like

```
GET /index/type/_search?search_type=count
```

Study more about `search_type` [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-type.html#count).

You can also refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472373/unexplainable-count-results-in-elasticsearch)